# Unknown attribute layout_width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am working on android project, all was working well, until suddenly I opened Android Studio and found warnings all my layout files. E.g unknown attribute android:layout_width, unknown attribute android:id etc. I tried creating a new layout resource file and it also did the same, only options available now are constraint_width,height and so on. What could be my problem here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just on menu bar invalide caches and restart Android-Studio: 
File -> Invalide Caches/Restart

That should help

Comment: okay, could you provide code of the layout which provides an error?

Comment: the screenshot above has the layout

Answer (score 0):

In your android studio try steps below:

1. File -> close project
2. From the list click on the "X" button in front of your project to remove it from the recent projects (As marked in image).

[image]

3. Click "open an existing Android Studio project", browse and select your project and reopen it.
4. By step 3 problem should be solved, if it wasn't, click Build -> Rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but resolved by invalidating caches and restarting android studio:
 Go to Android Studio: File -> Invalide Caches/Restart.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggested solutions worked, I had to remove all my configuration settings, gradle files and uninstall AS, redownloading it was the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes **File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.**  doesn't work, so do the manual clearing of the cache

**1. Closed Android Studio.**

**2. Clear the contents of the** C:\Users\MyUsername.AndroidStudio3.3\system\caches\ directory.

**3. Relaunched Android Studio.**